# looping through Javascript array and displaying HTML (knockout)

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I want to display JSON data which is my model. This is an example of what could be in it:

```
{"id":"1","name":"1","category":"A" },
{"id":"2","name":"2","category":"B" },
{"id":"3","name":"3","category":"A" },
{"id":"4","name":"4","category":"B" }
```

What I want is distinct al categories with javascript into an array i guess:
A B.

And then foreach element in array matching cat A print it like so with knockout:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: template, foreach: LISTOFITEMS }"></div>

<script id="template">
<h1 data-bind="text: Category></h1>
<div data-bind=" foreach: LISTOFITEMSmatchingcategory ">
<li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</div> 
</script>
```

Is this the way to go? I want to make stuff easily sortable (the array is an observable array)

Comment: I think you should create two observable arrays , based on category `A` and `B` and then use `foreach` for both of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way: -

```js
var self = this;

self.listArr = ko.observableArray([
     {"id":"1","name":"1","category":"A" },
     {"id":"2","name":"2","category":"B" },
     {"id":"3","name":"3","category":"A" },
     {"id":"4","name":"4","category":"B" }                             
]);

self.listA = ko.observableArray([]);
self.listB = ko.observableArray([]);

for(var i in self.listArr())
  {
      if(self.listArr()[i].category == "A")
        {
          self.listA.push(self.listArr()[i]);
        }
      else if(self.listArr()[i].category == "B")
        {
          self.listB.push(self.listArr()[i]);
        }
    }

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>List A</div>
<div data-bind="foreach:listA">
 <span data-bind= "text : $data.name"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
<div>List B</div>
<div data-bind="foreach:listB">
 <span data-bind= "text : $data.name"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```